How to do multiple SignOut in ASP.NET Core MVC?
I want to make two different SignOut panel(for Writers and Admins) in ASP.NET Core MVC with N-Tier architecture. I tried many things to do this but I couldn't.
SignIn and SignOut process works correctly for Admins, but for Writers, SignIn works correctly, SignOut does not work. It directs me to the Admin login page. I do not know what should I do.
I defined Writer and Admin schemes and called them with Authenticate attribute. Also, I am sure about that I assign the correct action and controller in .cshtml page.
Program.cs:
using BusinessLayer.Abstract;
using BusinessLayer.Concrete;
using DataAccessLayer.Abstract;
using DataAccessLayer.Concrete;
using DataAccessLayer.Concrete.Repositories;
using DataAccessLayer.EntityFramework;
using EntityLayer.Concrete;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MVC_Proje_Kamp.Controllers;
using System.Security.Claims;

namespace MVC_Proje_Kamp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(AppContext.BaseDirectory)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .Build();

            var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("mssqlconnection");

            builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
            builder.Services.AddSession();

            builder.Services.AddScoped<AdminManager>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<IAdminDal, EfAdminDal>();

            builder.Services.AddScoped<WriterManager>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<IWriterService, WriterManager>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<IWriterDal, EfWriterDal>();

            builder.Services.AddScoped<IContentService, ContentManager>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<IContentDal, EfContentDal>();

            builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

            builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = "AdminScheme"; 
            })
            .AddCookie("AdminScheme", options =>
                {
                    options.LoginPath = "/Login/Index";
                    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Login/Index";
                    options.Cookie.Name = "AdminScheme";
                    })
            .AddCookie("WriterScheme", options =>
                {
                    options.LoginPath = "/WriterPanelLogin/WriterLogin";
                    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/WriterPanelLogin/WriterLogin";
                    options.Cookie.Name = "WriterScheme";
                    options.LogoutPath = "/WriterPanelLogin/WriterLogOut";
                });

            // Authorization Check
            builder.Services.AddMvc(config =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            });

            var app = builder.Build();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/ErrorPage/Page404");
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "Default",
                pattern: "{controller=Category}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}

LoginController (for admin):
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    AdminManager adminManager = new AdminManager(new EfAdminDal());

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // LogIn
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(Admin p)
    {
        var context = adminManager.LogIn(p);

        if (context != null)
        {
            await HttpContext.SignInAsync("AdminScheme", context);

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "AdminCategory");
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }

    // Logout   
    public async Task<IActionResult> LogOut()
    {
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("AdminScheme");

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
    }
}

WriterPanelLoginController:
public class WriterPanelLoginController : Controller
{
     private readonly WriterManager _writerManager;

     public WriterPanelLoginController(WriterManager writerManager)
     {
         _writerManager = writerManager;
     }

     [AllowAnonymous]
     [HttpGet]
     public IActionResult WriterLogin()
     {
         return View();
     }

     [AllowAnonymous]
     [HttpPost]
     public async Task<IActionResult> WriterLogin(Writer p)
     {
         var login = _writerManager.LogIn(p);

         if (login != null)
         {
             await HttpContext.SignInAsync("WriterScheme", login);

             return RedirectToAction("MyHeadings", "WriterPanel");
         }

         return RedirectToAction("WriterLogin");
     }
     
     // Logout
     public async Task<IActionResult> WriterLogOut()
     {
         await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("WriterScheme");

         return RedirectToAction("WriterLogin", "WriterPanelLogin");
     }
}

WriterPanelController:
public class WriterPanelController : Controller
{
    HeadingManager headingManager = new HeadingManager(new EfHeadingDal());
    CategoryManager categoryManager = new CategoryManager(new EfCategoryDal());
    WriterManager writerManager = new WriterManager(new EfWriterDal());

    public IActionResult WriterProfile()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "WriterScheme")]
    public IActionResult MyHeadings()
    {
        var values = headingManager.GetListByWriter();

        return View(values);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult NewHeading()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> category = (from i in categoryManager.GetCategoryList()
                                         select new SelectListItem
                                         {
                                             Text = i.CategoryName,
                                             Value = i.CategoryId.ToString()
                                         }).ToList();

        ViewBag.categories = category;

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult NewHeading(Heading p)
    {
        p.HeadingDate = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
        p.WriterId = 3;
        p.HeadingStatus = true;
        headingManager.HeadingAdd(p);

        return RedirectToAction("MyHeadings", "WriterPanel");
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Update(int id)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> category = (from i in categoryManager.GetCategoryList()
                                         select new SelectListItem
                                         {
                                             Text = i.CategoryName,
                                             Value = i.CategoryId.ToString()
                                         }).ToList();

        ViewBag.categories = category;

        var update = headingManager.GetById(id);

        return View(update);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Update(Heading p)
    {
        p.WriterId = 3;
        headingManager.HeadingUpdate(p);

        return RedirectToAction("MyHeadings");
    }

    public IActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        var delete = headingManager.GetById(id);
        delete.HeadingStatus = false;
        headingManager.HeadingDelete(delete);

        return RedirectToAction("MyHeadings");
    }
}

AdminCategoryController:
public class AdminCategoryController : Controller
{
    CategoryManager categoryManager = new CategoryManager(new EfCategoryDal());

    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "AdminScheme", Roles = "B")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var categoryValues = categoryManager.GetCategoryList();

        return View(categoryValues);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult AddCategory()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AddCategory(Category p)
    {
        CategoryValidator categoryValidator = new CategoryValidator();
        ValidationResult result = categoryValidator.Validate(p);

        if (result.IsValid)
        {
            categoryManager.CategoryAdd(p);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(error.PropertyName, error.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }

        return View(p);
    }

    public IActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        var delete = categoryManager.GetById(id);
        categoryManager.CategoryDelete(delete);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Update(int id)
    {
        var update = categoryManager.GetById(id);

        return View(update);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Update(Category p)
    {
        categoryManager.CategoryUpdate(p);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}

I get help from many AI and web but I could not solve this problem.

I suspect that it's the default scheme is the admin scheme in your program.cs - so it could be going down that hole. Hence if you have no login / authentication then it'll go to the admin login

Yes you are right, default scheme is AdminScheme but I do not know how to fix this problem. It is my first time at this process and I get educated in .net 5.0 but I use 8.0. it is problem to adapt from older version to new one.

Could you try to add [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "WriterScheme")] attribute on your WriterPanelController ? And tell me the result, tks~

Unfortunately nothing changed again. Problem is only at Writer Logout. It directs me to Admin Login Page although Logut path is correct.

Hi codAction, it seems like there's a subtle thing we've overlooked, so I'd like you to create a repo with a reproducible issue and I'd be willing to debug and investigate the issue.

If there are some sensitive information in your project, please hide it,many thanks

Hi Jason Pan, I am sorry for replying late.
https://github.com/mehmetakifacar/Genel_Blog_Uygulamasi
here is my repo. My project haven't finished yet, there are missing parts. Thanks a lot for your interest.
